# How to Close Powerpoint Presentation after done and go back to original Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a presentation in which i'm running in a kiosk mode. User can click on some clickable items, and open other presentations. 
Apparently, these presentations are also opened in kiosk mode, although i want them to be in speaker mode.
Therefore, i replaced the clickable items with a macro which is opening the presentations and its default is Speaker mode.

The problem, and therefore the questions:
When working in the first mode, the internal presentation got opened, and when done, it got closed.
Using my Macro, which now opening the presentation, it remains opened even after done and going back to original presentation.

How do i "catch" the event and get it closed?

Comment: Will you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, linked presentations inherit whatever mode the original presentation is in.  Try starting the main presentation in Browsed By A Presenter (Full Screen) rather than Kiosk mode.

An End Show button on the linked presentation will close it and return you to the original presentation.  Regardless of how you opened the linked presentation (link or macro) that should work for you.